# Command line option for --help being applied to wrong command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, command-line, command-line-interface

I have a shell script for kicking off a rails script:

```
bin/rails runner script/sync-test.rb $@
```

The sync-test.rb script uses optparse and I want to allow the user to pass '--help' to the sync-test.rb script.  However, right now the rails runner executable is 'grabbing' --help.

Is there a way to force the sync-test.rb script to hold onto any CLI flags?  I tried:

```
bin/rails runner -- "script/sync-development-testdb.rb $@"
```

And that says to

```
Run 'script/rails -h' for help.
```

So it must not like that.

Comment: `bin/rails runner -- script/sync-development-testdb.rb $@` (without quotes) should be the right syntax. `--` should tell runner to ignore subsequent flags.

Comment: That still doesn't work. The rails runner tool thinks I'm passing it to runner in addition to the filename

Comment: That will cause the runner to ignore the script filename. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interactive prompt inside of `sync-test.rb`:

```
def ask_for_help
  print "Enter --help for help"
  case gets.chomp
  when "--help"
    puts 'ls --help'
  else
    puts 'ls'
  end
end

help = nil
until(help)
  help = ask_for_help()
end

print help, "\n"
```

**References**

- [Class String: method chomp](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/String.html#method-i-chomp)
- [Ruby Tutorial: Getting User Input](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/Tutorial/part_02/user_input.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add a line in your script to detect the ignore next flags operator `--`

```
ARGV.shift if ARGV.first == '--'
```

Then run with `bin/rails runner script/sync-development-testdb.rb -- $@`